# Inverse of a special matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, matrix-equations

Is there easy (analytical) way to find the inverse of the following matrix, where $C$ is a vector?
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & C^\top \\ 
C & CC^\top
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: Maybe this will be useful for you: http://www.math.chalmers.se/~rootzen/highdimensional/blockmatrixinverse.pdf

Comment: Lookup block inverse on wikipedia.

Comment: I think that you can't invert such a matrix, because I believe that it would always be singular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The matrix has no inverse, unless $C$ is the null vector and the matrix is $[1]$.

The matrix is an outer product of the vector $[1\quad  C^T]$. All outer product matrices have rank one, meaning it is rank deficient.

For instance, let $C^T=[x,y]$ then 
$$
CC^T=\left[\begin{array}{cc}x^2&xy\\xy&y^2\end{array}\right]
$$
and
$$
\left[\begin{array}{cc}1&C^T\\C&CC^T\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}1&x&y\\x&x^2&xy\\y&xy&y^2\end{array}\right]
$$
In which the columns are clearly all multiples of one another.

Answer (score 1):

Such a matrix cannot be invertible, since

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & C^\top \\ 
C & CC^\top
\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\ 
C
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 &
C^\top
\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\ 
C
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\ 
C
\end{bmatrix}
^\top$$
is rank one and the dimensions are larger than one.